# SharePoint 2010 Fast Search not crawling complex urls

Tags: sharepoint-server, fast-search, crawl-rules

So I'm working with a client that is using Fast Search to crawl a SharePoint 2010 Publishing site.  For the most part it is working fine, except they have "news" and "events" pages that are dynamically generating content from lists.  The content is a list of news articles or events with complex urls like **protocol://server/site/sub-site/pages/news-details.aspx?List=SOMEGUID&Item=4**.  The "news" and "events" pages are being crawled, but it appears to be ignoring the links generated within the web-part as I'm not seeing any of the referenced pages in the crawl log or search results.

I've checked everything I know to check:

1. Made sure **Library Settings** > **Advanced Settings** > **Allow items from this document library to appear in search results** is set to **Yes**.
2. Made sure **Site Settings** > **Search and Offline Availability** > **Indexing ASPX Page Content** is set to **Always index all Web Parts on this site**
3. Tried several iterations of crawl rules (broad to specific) with **Crawl complex URLs** and **Crawl SharePoint content as http pages** both set.
4. Made sure the pages in question were published.

I'm stumped.  Any suggestions on what I may be missing are greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I found out what was causing the problem.  My client is making heavy use of the URL Rewrite module in IIS.  I went through and disabled all the rules and SharePoint proceeded to crawl complex urls.  Still need to reconcile the two, but at least I know what was causing the problem.  Going to close this question...will see if I have to ask a new one. :)

Just a FYI for anyone who comes across this, here is Microsoft's official supportability statement on SharePoint and Rewrites/Redirects:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2818415

Answer (score 0):

Check if the pages are actually published and not only saved in SharePoint. (They should have a version number like 1.0 and not 0.1) Draft pages are not crawled by the crawler.

Comment: Should have added that to my "checked everything..." list. That was the 1st thing I checked.